# AnyObject to NsDictionery

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, nsdictionary, pfobject

How can i convert this javascript data to ios compatible data and put it in a dictionary, when i do something like this newCustomer["cvc_check"] etc nothing comes up i get a nil, l am trying to get data from parse PFCloud.callFunctioninBackground which is calling a stripe.com api to get those results

```
func hasToken(token: STPToken!) {

var parameters = ["cardToken":token.tokenId,
                  "objectId":PFUser.currentUser().objectId]

    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("createCustomer", withParameters:parameters) {
        (results: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !error {

            var newCustomer = results as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            println(newCustomer["cvc_check"]) // This gives me a nil

            self.successfulPayment()
        } else {
            let message = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
            self.hasError("\(message) Please try agains.")
        }
    }
```

[image: my Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to use `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`?

Comment: i have tried jason its giving me this kind of data 61726422 2c226164 64726573 735f6369 7479223a 6e756c6c 2c226376

Comment: Is 'results' a NSString? If so, you should convert the NSString to NSData `[dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and then call `[NSJsonSerialization jsonObjectWithData]` which can return you a NSDictionary.

Comment: hi guys the results are an array

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line:

```
var newCustomer = results as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

As you said in your comment, results is an `Array`, so this line should be:

```
var newCustomer = results as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
```

Does that help?